# Chunking File Lines Between Two Delimiters

Tags: ruby, alphabetical

I'm new to ruby (sort of) and I'm trying to figure out how to chunk certain portions(lines) of a file together so that I can later alphabetize the first lines of each chunk. I haven't been able to find this.

I've found out about file I/O and the problems with uploading large files into memory, but that isn't a concern as my file is statically ~70kB.

What I'm asking for is how to chunk lines of a file together between 2 different delimiters and exclude everything else in the file that does not fit the criteria.

ie.

file.txt =

```
//RandomComment
someObject:{
 someKey:someValue
},

//Another Random Comment
someOtherObject:{
 someKey:someValue
}
```

and that resolve to

```
someObject:{
  someKey:someValue      //chunk 1
},
someOtherObject:{
 someKey:someValue       //chunk 2
}
```

My delimiters in this case would be if the line includes a "{" and everything between that and the subsequent line that includes a "}"

Here's my ruby so far:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'

if File.exist?(filePath)
     File.open(filePath,"r") do |f|
      f.chunk { |line|
        line.include? "{" || "}"
      }.each { |_, lines|
        puts lines
      }
     end
    end
```

I would appreciate any help on this thanks

Comment: Is the file in json format? If so there is a dedicated library for parsing json files.

Answer (score 0):

**NB** *Disclamer*: One should never use regular expressions to parse long text input.

```
▶ input = '//RandomComment
▷ someObject:{
▷  someKey:someValue
▷ },
▷
▷ //Another Random Comment
▷ someOtherObject:{
▷  someKey:someValue
▷ }'
▶ input.scan /^[^\r\n]*{[^}]*[^\r\n]*/

#⇒ [
#    "someObject:{\n  someKey:someValue\n},",
#    "someOtherObject:{\n someKey:someValue\n}"
# ]
```

Comment: The `▷`s are pretty but they kind of make your code a pain to copy-and-paste.

Comment: @Jordan I am aware of that, but here on SO I expect the ratio 100:1 of just readers of the code to those who is to copy-paste it. For readers these pry markers make the code more readable, plus it makes _me_ easier to copy-paste things from pry. And yes, nowadays code editors support column editing out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If `text` is your string:

```
puts text.split.select { |line|
  line.include?("{")..line.include?("}") ? true : false }.join("\n")

someObject:{
someKey:someValue
},
someOtherObject:{
someKey:someValue
}
```

If you only want

```
["someKey:someValue\n", "someKey:someValue\n"]
```

returned, insert

```
.reject { |e| e =~ /\{|\}/ }
```

before `.join`.

This uses Ruby's ["flip-flop"](https://matousek.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/ruby-flip-flop-operator/) operator.

Lines are rejected until a line contain a left brace is found. `true` is returned for that line and every subsequently until a line containing a right brace is found. `true` is returned for the right-brace line, and then `false` is returned until another line containing a left brace is found, and so on. Hence, the name "flip-flop".

It may seem that `(e==1..e==2) ? true : false` could be simplified to `(e==1..e==2)`, but that is not the case, as the latter expression is treated as a normal range. Flip-flops must have a conditional form.

Comment: I had forgotten all about the flip-flop operator. Thanks for the reminder!